# Are there any alternative to Adobe Community forum?

Tags: animation, adobe, after-effects, adobe-animate

I want to know best forums in 2D animation industry. I know Adobe forum and Creative Cow as forum and Dribbble as community but I want to get interactive with more communities. Can you please help me discover them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few active subreddits on Reddit. First that comes to mind are [r/motiondesign](https://www.reddit.com/r/motiondesign) and [r/aftereffects](https://www.reddit.com/r/aftereffects).